# Issue with Start Button on Android Calculator

Tags: java, android, xml

I am working on an Android calculator app not using any of the built in timer based classes in Android, but instead using Handlers and Threads to update the UI. I'm not sure if there is a problem with my logic or not, but for whatever reason when I set a time and hit the Start button, nothing happens on the screen at all. The targeted TextView does not decrease as it should. Again, I may have made a simple errors (or a few), but I am posting my java and xml files for you all to look at. Thanks in advance for any responses.

TimerActivity.java

```
package com.example.stins.intentsandtimer;


import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Vibrator;



public class TimerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView hours, minutes, seconds;
    Button numberPicker;
    private int hrs, min, sec;
    private boolean start;

    Handler timerHandler = new Handler(){

        /**
         * Handler for the timer class. It receives the onStart runnable to allow the textviews
         * to be updated. It checks to see if all textviews are empty and only updates them if
         * they follow the conditions of a traditional timer.  Including moving from 1 hour to 59 minutes.
         * The handler also sends the Vibrator function once the timer is complete.
         * @param msg
         */
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            TextView txtSeconds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_seconds);
            TextView txtMinutes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_minutes);
            TextView txtHours = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_hours);
            int zeroCheck = Integer.parseInt(txtSeconds.getText().toString());

            if (zeroCheck > 0) {
                sec -= 1;
                txtSeconds.setText(sec + "");
            } else if (min > 0 && sec == 0) {
                min -= 1;
                txtMinutes.setText(min + "");
                sec = 59;
                txtSeconds.setText(sec + "");
            } else if (hrs > 0 && min == 0 && sec == 0) {
                hrs -= 1;
                txtHours.setText(hrs + "");
                min = 59;
                txtMinutes.setText(min + "");
                sec = 59;
                txtSeconds.setText(sec + "");
            } else {
                Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                v.vibrate(1000);
            }
        }

    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);
        this.setTitle("Timer");

        Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        Button btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
        Button btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset_button);


        hours = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_hours);
        numberPicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_set_hours);
        numberPicker.setOnClickListener(this);

        minutes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_minutes);
        numberPicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_set_minutes);
        numberPicker.setOnClickListener(this);

        seconds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_seconds);
        numberPicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_set_seconds);
        numberPicker.setOnClickListener(this);


        btnReset.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View view) {
                                            TextView txtSeconds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_seconds);
                                            TextView txtMinutes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_minutes);
                                            TextView txtHours = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_hours);
                                            sec = 0;
                                            min = 0;
                                            hrs = 0;
                                            txtSeconds.setText(sec+"");
                                            txtMinutes.setText(min+"");
                                            txtHours.setText(hrs+"");

                                        }
                                    }
        );

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View view) {
                                            start = true;
                                            onStart();
                                        }
                                    }
        );

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                                       public void onClick(View view) {
                                           start = false;
                                       }
                                   }
        );


    }

    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        final Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (sec > 0 || min > 0 || hrs > 0) {
                    if(start) {
                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            timerHandler.sendMessage(timerHandler.obtainMessage());
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                }

            }

        });
        myThread.start();
    }




    public void onClick (View v){
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btn_set_hours:
                hourPickerDialog();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_set_minutes:
                minutePickerDialog();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_set_seconds:
                secondPickerDialog();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }


    }



    private void hourPickerDialog(){
        NumberPicker myNumberPicker = new NumberPicker(this);
        myNumberPicker.setMaxValue(99);
        myNumberPicker.setMinValue(0);
        NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener myValChangedListener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                hours.setText(""+newVal);
            }
        };
        myNumberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(myValChangedListener);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(myNumberPicker);
        builder.setTitle("Set Hours");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        builder.show();


    }

    private void minutePickerDialog(){
        NumberPicker myNumberPicker = new NumberPicker(this);
        myNumberPicker.setMaxValue(59);
        myNumberPicker.setMinValue(0);
        NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener myValChangedListener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                minutes.setText(""+newVal);
            }
        };
        myNumberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(myValChangedListener);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(myNumberPicker);
        builder.setTitle("Set Minutes");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        builder.show();


    }

    private void secondPickerDialog(){
        NumberPicker myNumberPicker = new NumberPicker(this);
        myNumberPicker.setMaxValue(59);
        myNumberPicker.setMinValue(0);
        NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener myValChangedListener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                seconds.setText(""+newVal);
            }
        };
        myNumberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(myValChangedListener);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(myNumberPicker);
        builder.setTitle("Set Seconds");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        builder.show();


    }


}
```

activity_timer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_margin="16dp"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_hours"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="00"
            android:textSize="70sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text=":"
            android:textSize="70sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_minutes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="00"
            android:textSize="70sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text=":"
            android:textSize="70sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_seconds"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="00"
            android:textSize="70sp" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_set_hours"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hours"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_set_minutes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Minutes"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_set_seconds"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Seconds"/>



    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:text="@string/timer_start"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:text="@string/timer_stop"
        style="@style/MyButton"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:text="@string/timer_reset"
        style="@style/MyButton"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several things going on in your code.  I won't try to address them all but just some to get your code doing about what it should.  I've copied & tried your code & it actually changes the display for me.  I skipped your time picker dialogs & just set `sec=20` to start.  If you're not getting any changing display, is the display being set initially from the time pickers?

Anyway, 1st let's talk about debugging.  One way to do this is to put Log statements in your code.  Start by putting this at the top of the file

```
private final static String TAG = "TimerActivity";
```

Then in the code have things like this:

```
// put this in the start button click listener
Log.d(TAG, "Start clicked");

// or this in handleMessage
Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage(), seconds = " + sec);
```

Having these Log message can help you know what your program has done & what it hasn't, plus show you some variable values.  You could also use the debugger which I won't get into now.

Now for your code.  `onStart()` is a lifecycle method.  You should not call it yourself.  Rename your method (maybe something like `onStartButton()`).  As you have it now, you have 2 instances of your thread running and your counter goes down twice in each second.

In `handleMessage()`, you have variables (hrs, min, sec) that you use to track the time but you also have `zeroCheck` that you read from the text on the display.  The better thing to do would be use the variables you're already keeping anyway (`if(sec > 0) { sec -= 1;...`).  I didn't verify your logic in the rest of these conditions.  Once the display is updating, I'll leave that for you.

Lastly, `txtSeconds.setText(sec + "");` is not a good way to use `setText()` (it's probably OK for Log messages but it's better to get accustomed to using text in other ways).  There is more than 1 good way to display text but for this instance, you need special formatting.  That is you want your display to show a leading 0 for each number "00:09:07" not "0:9:7".  You can get that with

```
txtSeconds.setText(String.format("%02d", sec));
```

This way always gives a 2 digit display, from 0 to 59.  Other useful formatters are "%08x" for 32 bit hexadecimal or "%.2f" which limits display to 2 places past the decimal place like for showing dollars and cents.

So, none of these will fix the problem in your post but they will get your final code closer to what it needs to be.  As I said, your code updates the display as it is for me (not using the time pickers).  You can start by setting `sec` to a fixed number then hit the "Start" button to see what happens.  If there are problems in your time pickers, you can use Log messages to track down the bugs & fix them.

**EDIT:**

So what's happening with your timer not starting is that, while you change the display in your number picker, you don't set the underlying variables (`sec` etc.)  Define some variables to use as temp storage (`temp_sec` etc.) then set this in `onValueChange()`,

```
temp_sec = newVal;
```

Now in your positiveButton `onClick()`, you'll have

```
sec = temp_sec;
```

Comment: Wow!! Thanks so much! I'm still getting used to using the Log messages. So thanks so much for the tips and the others as well. Going back in now to apply these and get to the root of the issue.

Comment: Oh, one more thing, you said it did update the display for you when the value was not set with the number pickers, is that right?

Comment: That's correct.  I was lazy & didn't want to deal with the number pickers so I just put this in the file `private int hrs=0, min=0, sec=20;`

Comment: ah! okay. Yeah I thought the number pickers may give me a bit of a headache. I read about how to implement them for a while before actually adding those dialogs, but are you aware of any further steps I may need to take to have those values that are set by the number pickers actually start to update as well?

Comment: Many thanks for that edit, helped so much! Now I just need to work out that decreasing twice issue on the textviews.

Comment: That's where `onStart()` is affecting you.  `onStart()` is a lifecycle method.  You can (& sometimes should) put code in it but you shouldn't call it from another method.  In this case, it's executed once as part of the lifecycle & then again when you call it after "Start" is clicked.  You're not using it as part of the lifecycle so change its name & you'll be OK.  See this to learn about Activity lifecycles https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html